# jQuery - Keep toggled element after page reload

Tags: jquery, session, refresh, toggle, slide

As you can see in the code below, I have a button that makes a div to slideToggle.

```
$(function goesUp() {
  $(".goes_up").click(function(){
      $('.toggle_logo').slideToggle("slow");
      $(this).toggleClass("goes_down");
  });
});
```

As this div is in the header, I'd like to keep my element open or closed as it was before the page reload. What's the right way to do it?

Comment: You can do it using **[sessionStorage](https://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/)**

Answer (score 0):

The web is stateless, so if you want to persist any changes you'll need to store it somewhere and recreate those changes when the page reloads.

Where you store it is up to you and will be dictated by what you want to do.
You could set a cookie and read its value using jQuery/JavaScript on each page load.

You could store it on the server, maybe as part of the user's session and recreate the page from there each time.

You could store it in a database and make the change permanent across all sessions for that user.

The exact solution will depend on what you're trying to achieve by persisting the change.

Answer (score 0):

Or, set create a boolean value for something like 'toggled' and save it in local storage on the users computer. If the user clicks on '.goesUp', assign 'toggled' to true. Then check to see if 'toggled' is true or false on load, have it display accordingly.

W3schools for local storage http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp